# c# recursion on an xml file containing links to dozens of other xml files that i want to loop through entirely

Tags: c#, xml, recursion

I am trying to figure out how to create a recursive function to read an initial xml document, identical to below.

Every href attribute in these nodes is a link. "" + that href value.

The recursive loop would open an xdoc for each of those.

Notice that some say folder, and some video. i want to create a folder for each folder, a text file for each video listing that href. so nearly identical to the classic  recursive example of recursion of a folder/file tree.

Any suggestions? i've tried doing a double set of foreach loops, adding hrefs to lists and then iterating through them but no matter what i try, i never get the folder structure right and if i write a file i always end up overwriting it with whatever comes next.

for reference, it's from playon app and this is the "Recently added" list of netflix.

here's a simple path example that goes from: netflix user -> my list -> a tv show -> tv show seasons ->

## Start of folder tree

```
<group name="Netflix" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix" type="folder" art="/images/provider.png?id=netflix" searchable="true" id="netflix" childs="0" category="4099">
<group name="Taylor" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-73b43a5abf0b4d6086c0a6a2f11200ee" type="folder" childs="0"/>
<group name="Courtney" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-00a010f3321f4ca0ae7592a0126995e4" type="folder" childs="0"/>
<group name="Kids" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-76d20d377e1f49af9848b2335cb9199f" type="folder" childs="0"/>
<group name="Playback Options" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-6b2f5118e04e4072bfe48ab298d4a91f" type="folder" childs="0" art="/images/poster.jpg?id=netflix-6b2f5118e04e4072bfe48ab298d4a91f&size=tiny"/>
</group>
```

## Netflix/Taylor("localhost:54479" + href attribute value)

```
<group name="Taylor" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-73b43a5abf0b4d6086c0a6a2f11200ee" type="folder">
<group name="My List" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-98fad8d5a8f348a5b0cb3d7fe6e81ea9" type="folder" childs="0"/>
<group name="Continue Watching" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-755b5fb0bb4d4ccab84f92193b7ae10e" type="folder" childs="0"/>
<group name="Browse Genres" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-ebc7ba3576dd4cc38acc7478bab3a4ca" type="folder" childs="0"/>
<group name="Just for Kids" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-970a14c27f48488188b94d5734797415" type="folder" childs="0"/>
<group name="Top Picks for Taylor" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-745bb4c1d2ce43a5aaa24a25bc78f881" type="folder" childs="0"/>
<group name="Recently Added" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-0ce59d5a759f4c5c93df8428489c3cff" type="folder" childs="0"/>
<group name="Popular on Netflix" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-60802588a871490fa73f13c0ba673a80" type="folder" childs="0"/>
<group name="Suggestions For You" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-9491e584db7b4c0c918df7bfbb0e1fe4" type="folder" childs="0"/>
</group>
```

## NetFlix/Taylor/Mylist("localhost:54479"+href attribute value of 'my list' node)

```
<group name="My List" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-98fad8d5a8f348a5b0cb3d7fe6e81ea9" type="folder">
<group name="Africa" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-1947c3b0dc91480c8d31f0bfe60194ab" type="folder" childs="0" art="/images/poster.jpg?id=netflix-1947c3b0dc91480c8d31f0bfe60194ab&size=tiny"/>
<group name="Animals Gone Wild" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-0793a52b83d746bb8009de611ca48a63" type="folder" childs="0" art="/images/poster.jpg?id=netflix-0793a52b83d746bb8009de611ca48a63&size=tiny"/>
<group name="Ascension" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-f6945330c90443f6a889edee09ecd977" type="folder" childs="0" art="/images/poster.jpg?id=netflix-f6945330c90443f6a889edee09ecd977&size=tiny"/>
<group name="The Blue Planet: A Natural History of the Oceans" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-b811b457743f4cbbaffc066e01d3e5b5" type="folder" childs="0" art="/images/poster.jpg?id=netflix-b811b457743f4cbbaffc066e01d3e5b5&size=tiny"/>
<group name="Brain Games" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-9311dc81e85c4f20a192095c23fd3bf2" type="folder" childs="0" art="/images/poster.jpg?id=netflix-9311dc81e85c4f20a192095c23fd3bf2&size=tiny"/>
<group name="Breaking Bad" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-26775c743497400995f6440ef543c99d" type="folder" childs="0" art="/images/poster.jpg?id=netflix-26775c743497400995f6440ef543c99d&size=tiny"/>
<group name="Burn Notice" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-645b8cbeb2754f5cb77696298fff5e13" type="folder" childs="0" art="/images/poster.jpg?id=netflix-645b8cbeb2754f5cb77696298fff5e13&size=tiny"/>
<group name="The Road to El Dorado" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-c5a76a26075d40408485fa9c2ca0d72b" type="video" art="/images/poster.jpg?id=netflix-c5a76a26075d40408485fa9c2ca0d72b&size=tiny"/>
<group name="The Running Man" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-d19265cad13b498ea94a7f9e1b3d145c" type="video" art="/images/poster.jpg?id=netflix-d19265cad13b498ea94a7f9e1b3d145c&size=tiny"/>
</group>
```

## Netflix/Taylor/MyList/Breaking Bad

```
<group name="Breaking Bad" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-26775c743497400995f6440ef543c99d" type="folder" art="/images/poster.jpg?id=netflix-26775c743497400995f6440ef543c99d&size=tiny">
<group name="Season 1" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-a5b3b4541e764a3c839638ee6f374e1e" type="folder" childs="0" art="/images/poster.jpg?id=netflix-a5b3b4541e764a3c839638ee6f374e1e&size=tiny"/>
<group name="Season 2" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-0116f794675b4e2180aa182e22d4d7d0" type="folder" childs="0" art="/images/poster.jpg?id=netflix-a5b3b4541e764a3c839638ee6f374e1e&size=tiny"/>
<group name="Season 3" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-5789d013866b452a858dcc3321f13b5f" type="folder" childs="0" art="/images/poster.jpg?id=netflix-a5b3b4541e764a3c839638ee6f374e1e&size=tiny"/>
<group name="Season 4" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-fb480873895548e08f1bcd0e8e6275ce" type="folder" childs="0" art="/images/poster.jpg?id=netflix-a5b3b4541e764a3c839638ee6f374e1e&size=tiny"/>
<group name="Season 5" href="/data/data.xml?id=netflix-65d155a01fd244869fcda5728c7683ad" type="folder" childs="0" art="/images/poster.jpg?id=netflix-a5b3b4541e764a3c839638ee6f374e1e&size=tiny"/>
</group>
```

**the problem is that after it reaches season 5, and goes to the next tv show, i lose the folder tree from Netflix/Taylor/Mylist.  the next folder tree would start with the show name and lose anything before it.**

```
 private static void addfolder(string url, string parentFolder, string foldertree)
        {
            string baseurl = null;
            string lastFolder;
            string path = string.Empty;
            string tree = "";

            var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.Load(url);
            // xdoc.Save(Console.Out);


            var playonList = new List<Playon>();


            foreach (XmlNode groups in xdoc.DocumentElement)
            {
                if (groups.Attributes[2].Value == "folder")
                {
                    baseurl = "http://localhost:54479";
                    var netflix = "netflix\\";

                    path = path + "\\" + groups.Attributes[0].Value.Replace(":", "-");
                    playonList.Add(new Playon(groups.Attributes[1].Value, groups.Attributes[0].Value,
                        groups.Attributes[2].Value));
                    lastFolder = groups.Attributes[0].Value;
                    Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\streamertest\\" + path.Replace(":", "-"));
                    if (File.Exists("C:\\streamertest\\" + path.Replace(":", "-") + "\\data.xml"))
                        xdoc.Save("C:\\streamertest\\" + path.Replace(":", "-") + "\\data" + groups.Attributes[0] +
                                  ".xml");
                    else
                    {
                        xdoc?.Save("C:\\streamertest\\" + path.Replace(":", "-") + "\\data.xml");
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(groups.Attributes[0].Value);

                   addfolder(baseurl + groups.Attributes[1].Value, lastFolder, path.Replace(":","-"));

                }
            }
```

Comment: Short of "go and write recursive function that will do that" what actual concrete problem you are facing?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the main problem i am having is that my foldertree variable i've set is getting reset constantly with no apparent pattern. if you look at the list above, my function will create these folders: recently added, recently added/black road, black road, recently added/black road/ bon bin holland, bon bini holland, etc. i had recently rewrote my function to try using lists and i don't believe this one comes even close to working...i'm trying to find the one that almost worked so i can paste the code here.

Comment: Please check out [MCVE] guidance and [edit] question with one. Current code does not give any information why `foldertree` could be changing (it is not even used anywhere).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sorry, i meant path. i corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the start of the xml file is like what you posted earlier.  The xml identification is the first line and the folder element is the 2nd line.  I've been writing recursive methods for 40 years so this is real simple.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:54479";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "/data/data.xml?id=netflix";
            string directory = "C:\\streamertest";
            string path = "Netflix";
            addfolder(path, url, directory, 0);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static void addfolder(string path, string url, string directory, int level)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("{0} folder : '{1}'", new string('.', 5 * level), path);

            //Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(BASE_URL + url);
            XElement root = (XElement)xdoc.FirstNode;

            foreach (XElement element in root.Elements())
            {
                string type = (string)element.Attribute("type");
                string name = (string)element.Attribute("name");
                string href = (string)element.Attribute("href");
                switch (type)
                {
                    case "folder":
                        string newpath = path + "/" + name;
                        string newDirectory = directory + "\\" + name;
                        addfolder(newpath, href, newDirectory, level++);

                        break;
                    default:
                        string pathName = path + "/" + name;

                        Console.WriteLine("{0}   url : '{1}'", new string(' ', 5 * level), pathName);
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i definitely like the way you went about doing this better, but i'm not sure how i'd get a folder-tree going. the difficulty is that i can't figure out how to keep the folder tree together when a tv show switches. my current 'path' variable does this, where each pipe | is a new console.writeline.        netflix | netflix\name | netflix\name\Recently Added | netflix\name\Recently Added\TV Show | netflix\name\Recently Added\TV Show\season 1 | NEXT TV SHOW  | NEXT TV SHOW\Season 1.              it loses the original netflix\name\category when the show changes.

Comment: From the inputs you provided I don't see any tree structure. Your xml only shows one layer so I can't assume anything.  That is why I removed the recursion.  If you provided a multi-layered xml I can better see if recursion is needed.

Comment: I'll add a second file, but I'll have to use a different category. Do you see the href attribute? Each of those is another xml file. It's netflix so, each of those href is another layer. Click on...'TV shows' on netflix, it'll load another xml layer showing you tv show genres, then a list of shows per genre, then a list of seasons, etc. And each of the new layers requires me to load a new xdocument using localhost:port/hrefAttributeValue .

Comment: i added enough xml files to go to one show. when the last season hits is where the folder tree is destroyed and starts back at the tv-show instead of keeping netflix/taylor/mylist in front of it. so in that list after breaking bad...it should be..netflix/taylor/my list/burn notice/season1 but it's only burn notice/season 1

Comment: I'm guessing a little bit about the xml file.  The pieces you posted don't tell me the real structure.  I updated the code.

Comment: they are different xml files, that's what the biggest hurdle is. each of those href's is me doing a call to another xml file. likewise, each of those xml pieces above is from a different xml file. localhost:54479/data/data/xml?id=netflix is the beginning of each, followed by the value of each of those individual nodes. so for the first one that lists 'taylor, courtney, kids, and playback options, there are four links to 4 seperate xml files on that initial netflix xml file.

Comment: I updated the code.  I think Netflix needs to be part of the baseUrl string but not sure

Comment: What is the url for 'Start of Folder Tree'?